# camera Barcode scanner for all devices

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I am building a scavenger hunt game for a library and would like to have a feature where the player can scan the book's barcode as an input for a correct answer.

I am building the app on Dreamweaver with HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Is there any way for me to access the phone's camera and use it to scan a barcode, then match that barcode to a correct answer? I'm not trying to find the book on Amazon or anything.

Comment: Zbar reader is great for native iOS and android, but I don't know how you would use them the way you are building your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are native libraries like ZXing and Zbar which will do that very easily for you. But the part of the app which does the scanning will have to coded natively. Web Pages cannot decode QR's. If that is what you require you will need to upload a live stream of the camera footage and run a decoding logic on a server. But you will be unnecessarily complicating things.